# Как выполнить запрос посредством CURL в PHP?

Tags: php-curl

В документации написано:

```
Получение информации по области по названию.
Позволяет получить перечень областей и выполнить поиск по части названия.
Параметры, передаваемые в запросе:
region_name – наименование области;
region_name_en – наименование области на английском.
GET Request
URI:/get_regions_by_region_ua?region_name={region_name}&region_name_en={region_na
me_en}
```

Помогите составить запрос.

Посредством file_get_contents:

```
$url = "https://www.xxxxxx/get_regions_by_region_ua?region_name=''&region_name_en=''";

$result = file_get_contents($url, null, stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer xxx-xxx-xxx")
    ),
)));

var_dump($result); //bool(false)
```

Comment: Если нужен get запрос, можно спокойно обойтись `file_get_contents`

Comment: Попробовал через file_get_contents, получаю false

Comment: [примеры есть в документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-init.php)